# Guild join event prints the bot was invited -- Discord.py

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py, bots

I'm unsure how I would code a command/event that would print out the list of guilds that the bot was in whenever the bot was added to a new server. I know how to print the list of servers themselves, but I don't know the condition that would allow me to check when the bot has been added to a new server. I've been searching online but have had no luck.

```py
@bot.event
async def on_bot_join(bot):
    if # condition that sends true when the bot has been added to a new server
        print('Bot has been added to a new server')
        print('List of servers the bot is in: ')
        for guild in bot.guilds:
            await print(guild.name)
```

It would be even more helpful if someone could tell me how to print only the name of the new server that the bot was added to, rather than all of them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's `on_guild_join`, it does not require `bot` for the event parameters.

Instead, you pass `guild` and use `on_guild_join` as your event. Here's it applied to your question,

```
@bot.event
async def on_guild_join(guild):
    print('Bot has been added to a new server')
    print('List of servers the bot is in: ')

    for guild in bot.guilds:
        await print(guild.name)
```

You also don't need to use `if` when it is added

If you want to print just the guild, you can use as below and simply uses `guild`

```
@bot.event
async def on_guild_join(guild):
    print(f'Bot has been added to: {guild}')
```

Answer (score 1):

so I used this code in my own bot to see how it would work. First, I changed the `on_bot_join` event to `on_guild_join` then removed the bot parameter as it wasn't required for this event.

```
@bot.event
async def on_guild_join(guild):
 print('Bot has been added to a new server')
 print('List of servers the bot is in: ')
 for guild in bot.guilds:
    print(guild.name)
```

[image]

To print only the name of the server the bot join, just use `guild.name` and that should do it. Something like this:

```
@bot.event
async def on_guild_join(guild):
 print(f'Bot has been added to a new server: {guild.name}')
 print('List of servers the bot is in: ')
 for guilds in bot.guilds:
    print(guilds.name)
```

[image]